# Any good algorithm for this two-dimensional array quiz?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

counting and grouping the number near by

lets say we have a two-dimensional array for example,

```
a = [
          [5,4,4],
          [4,3,4],
          [3,2,4]
    ]
```

my goal counting the number group near by

for this situation
a[0][0] = 5 doesn't have the same number near by
(a[0][1], a[1][0] is not 5)
1 group

a[0][1] = 4 have the same number at a[0][2], a[1][2], a[2][2]
2 group

and finally, in this case,

there will be 6 groups in this example two-dimensional array.

quiz(a) = 6  -> expected.

programming language doesn't matter.

can somebody give an awesome algorithm for this? :(

Comment: This is called counting islands.

Answer (score 0):

Take the value of the array position as a variable, i.e. 
    array[i][j];
Then cycle through checking

```
while (i < MAX_I){
    if (array[i+1] == array[i] || array[i-1] == array[i]){ Do Something}
    i += 2;
}
while (J < MAX_J){
    if (array[j+1] == array[j] || array[j-1] == array[j]){ Do Something}
    i += 2;
}
```

Might not be the most efficient, but quite a simple one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Breadth First Search (BFS). For each element in the array you mark it as not visited. Then you iterate over each element and if it is not visited you do the following:

- Add this element to a queue and mark it as visited
- Increment variable indicating current group number
- While queue is not empty

  - Assign current group variable value to the first element in queue and remove it from the queue
  - For each not visited neighbour of this element which has the same value in array add it to the queue and mark it as visited

At the end you will have a group number for each element.

Answer (score 0):

DFS good enough for this problem:

This is very simple recursion function:
My pseudocode here:

```
function DFS(x, y, regionId)
{
  if (region[x,y] == regionId) return;
  region[x,y] = regionId;
  if (Inside(x-1, y) && (map[x-1,y] == map[x,y])) DFS(x-1, y, regionId);
  if (Inside(x+1, y) && (map[x+1,y] == map[x,y])) DFS(x+1, y, regionId);
  if (Inside(x, y-1) && (map[x,y-1] == map[x,y])) DFS(x, y-1, regionId);
  if (Inside(x, y+1) && (map[x,y+1] == map[x,y])) DFS(x, y+1, regionId);
}

Populate() 
{
  int regionId = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<maxX;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<maxY;j++)
      if (region[x,y] == 0)
      {
        DFS(i, j, ++regionId);
      }

  Console.Write("Total regions = " + regionId);
}
```

Comment: what does the Inside funtion do? i'm not clear in here

Comment: Point inside map or not, just check check array range.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Толя DFS is the solution for the above problem.
We group the elements using DFS & count them as one element. We do this procedure for each element.

Here is the sample code in Java..

```
public void test(){
    int[][] arr = new int[][]{ {5,4,4},
               {4,3,4},
               {3,2,4} };
    int cols = arr[0].length;
    int rows = arr.length;

    int count=0;

    //Iterate thru each element of the matrix
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){

            if(arr[i][j]==Integer.MIN_VALUE)  
                continue;

            dfs(arr,arr[i][j],i,j);
            count++;

         // Printing after every iteration ( code not required, hence commented )
         /* for(int i1=0;i1<rows;i1++){
                for(int j1=0;j1<cols;j1++)
                    System.out.print(" "+arr[i1][j1]);
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();*/

        }
    }

    System.out.println("No.of.groups = "+count);
}
```

Here is the DFS function

```
public void dfs(int[][] arr, int key,int row,int col){

        if(row>=arr.length || row<0)
            return;
        if(col>=arr[0].length || col<0)
            return;

        if(arr[row][col]!=key || arr[row][col]==Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            return;

        // Marking the visited element as 'MIN_VALUE'
        arr[row][col] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

        dfs(arr,key,row+1,col);
        dfs(arr,key,row-1,col);
        dfs(arr,key,row,col+1);
        dfs(arr,key,row,col-1);

    }
```